# Django HttpRequest type hint / annotation problem

Tags: python, django, pycharm, annotations, type-hinting

```py
def my_func(request: HttpRequest) -> str:
  return request.user.email
```

gives me a warning in PyCharm, saying that `user` is not a defined attribute. However writing it as
`request: HttpRequest()` removes this warning, and gives me proper parameters in suggestions. Could someone explain why this is happening, and if I did something wrong?

I'm importing HttpRequest from `django.http`.

Comment: The problem is that `HttpRequest` may have `user = None` (when not authenticated). Hinting as `HttpRequest()` is just invalid, so pycharm gives up and interprets it like `Any`, probably. You need to `assert request.user is not None` before using `user` (or handle `None` explicitly in `if-else` block).

Comment: @SUTerliakov HttpRequest never has user = None. When not authenticated, it's an instance of AnonymousUser and the official way is to check request.user.is_authenticated.

The error here is that the attribute comes from AuthenticationMiddleware, which is hard to express through the typings and mypy has no way to pick it up (and I guess isn't implemented in django-stubs).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was wrong, `user` attribute is always defined ([here](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/master/django-stubs/http/request.pyi#L48)) and never `None`. I guess the OP posts a wrong error message. The error should be about the `.email` attribute - `AnonymousUser` does not have it. Do you experience similar problem? Please consider opening a new question.

Comment: the attribute appears correctly on PyCharm now. It might've been fixed in the time since the question was raised.